# Adapting JavaScript to new rewrite rules

Tags: php, javascript, url-rewriting

This is my site:
http://www.globalmedicalaware.com/gma-new/home.php?city=Chennai

I changed the url to http://www.globalmedicalaware.com/gma-new/home/city/Chennai
by using .htaccess code like follow

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /city/(.*) home.php?city=$1
```

After that I clicked on to the any city on top header it changed like follow
http://www.globalmedicalaware.com/gma-new/home/city/Chennai?city=Chennai

because I used this JavaScript code to change the city value:

```
url=document.location.href.split('?')[0];
key='?city='+city;
window.location=url+key;
```

How can I change my JavaScript code to accommodate the new rewrite rules?

Comment: You can't rewrite the url from javascript. What you can do is change the way you are getting the key from the url.

Comment: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/

Comment: @AlphaMale Awesome link about URL rewriting tutorial for those who doesn't know it yet =D

Comment: Hi karthick, it is possible to rewrite the url from javascript by following code

<title>key = document.location.href.substring(0,document.location.href.indexOf("home"))+"home/city/"+city;

window.location=key;</title>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  This should help you get the old url :

```
var str = "http://www.globalmedicalaware.com/gma-new/home.php?city=Chennai";
url = str.substring(0,str.indexOf("home"))+"home.php?city="+city;
```

Comment: Thank you Nandu..but after put ur code,
http://www.globalmedicalaware.com/gma-new/home/city/Chennai?city=Chennai

<pre>?city=Chennai not appeared but when i change the city in top header,city not changed in url..please help me..thank you</pre>

Comment: Thank u nandu..but still lot of work in javascript to work that..but any way u only gave me the key..Thank u so much